# Daily new users count contains updating users, how to prevent this?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I use Fabric Answers to measure the behaviour of the users of my iOS app. The thing is, I have been using Fabric for the last half year, but my app already existed for 5 years before that.

Now, each user that updates to the latest version that came from a version without Fabric in it, is counted as a new daily user.

In my app, I do have a method to determine whether a user is updating from an older version (through the existence of certain NSUserDefaults settings). Is there a way to tell the Fabric SDK that the current user is not new?

Answer (score 0):

Todd from Fabric here. Answers does not count updates as new users in more [recent versions of our SDK](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-metrics.html#daily-new-users). I'd suggest updating your SDK version to the most recent to prevent this from happening.

Thanks!